# split a data.table in R by key

Tags: r, split, key, data.table, grouping

I have a `data.table` object in R that I would like to split along its keys.

```
>myTable[1:11]
   ID     length  hash
1: 2578   52.5   26566273
2: 4066   52.5   26566273
3: 2578   53.5   26566273
4: 4066   53.5   26566273
5: 2207   29.5   54352910
6: 3719   29.5   54352910
7: 5166    9.5  613353882
8: 5167    9.5  613353882
9: 5169    9.5  613353882
10:5170    9.5  613353882
11:5171    9.5  613353882
```

first_hash and length are my 2 keys
the output i would like is the list for each key of the ID column

so it could be something which looks like

```
first_hash length ID_list
26566273   52.5   [1] 2578 4066
26566273   53.5   [1] 2578 4066
54352910   29.5   [1] 2207 3719
613353882   9.5   [1] 5166 5167 5168 5169 5170 5171
```

or some kind of list...

i think `plyr` can give some answers to this, but I would prefer the `data.table` way

the ultimate goal is to create all pairs of ID having the same key
i am aware of the function `expand.grid`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'hash' and 'length' and place the 'ID' in a `list`.

```
DT <-  myTable[,list(ID_list=list(ID)) , by =.(first_hash=hash, length)]
DT
#   first_hash length                  ID_list
#1:   26566273   52.5                2578,4066
#2:   26566273   53.5                2578,4066
#3:   54352910   29.5                2207,3719
#4:  613353882    9.5 5166,5167,5169,5170,5171

str(DT)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ first_hash: int  26566273 26566273 54352910 613353882
# $ length    : num  52.5 53.5 29.5 9.5
# $ ID_list   :List of 4
# ..$ : int  2578 4066
# ..$ : int  2578 4066
# ..$ : int  2207 3719
# ..$ : int  5166 5167 5169 5170 5171
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can `paste` the 'ID' to create a column by group instead of a `list`

```
 myTable[,list(ID_list= toString(ID)) , by =.(first_hash=hash, length)]
```

Comment: `toString` is another common recommendation. Surprised I couldn't find a dupe.